# Add two or more functions to an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an image element and added attributes to it.
I also added a function to an onclick event by doing:

```
img.onclick = change;
```

Now I want to add another function which has a parameter to my onclick event. Lets say I want to add:

```
retrieveClass(this.className);
```

How can I do this? Something like...

```
 img.onclick = change, retrieveClass(this.className);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to have multiple event handlers triggered by a single event, the standard method is to use `addEventListener` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

Assuming in your sample, `change` is the name of a handler function, and `retrieveClass(this.className)` returns another handler function, you could do this:

```
img.addEventListener('click', change);
img.addEventListener('click', retrieveClass(this.className));
```

Answer (score 1):

`img.onclick = function () { change; retrieveClass(this.className); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) method which refers to the function, eg:

```js
img.onclick = retrieveClass.bind(img, img.className);
                                 ^^^
                                 this
```

is equivalent to:

```
img.onclick = function(){
   retrieveClass(this.className);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest...

```
<img src="..." onclick="command1; command2;">
```

You should use a function for this:

```
function imgClicked() {
    command1;
    command2;
}
```

Of course, you can declare it also with

```
img.onclick = function () { command1; command2; }
```

Comment: onclick attributes are bad practice

Comment: Yes, I wrote `This is the simplest...`. That you should use event handlers for this is totally my opinion.

Comment: that you should use event handlers is proveably the way, it leads to better separation of concerns, javascript modularity, re-use etc.

Comment: i'd actually suggest overall that binding is the simplest option, simply because it's easier to maintain, debug, re-use ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper function containing both function calls then bind that to your onclick.

```
function wrap() {
    change;
    retrieveClass(img.className);
}

img.onclick = wrap();
```